# Toolbar overlapping layout. I have tried many solutions none work

Tags: android, xml

My toolbar is over my layout and I want to fix it. I have tried these
[How to make Toolbar not overlap other content in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422236/how-to-make-toolbar-not-overlap-other-content-in-android)

[Android AppBarLayout overlaps listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653767/android-appbarlayout-overlaps-listview)

[Where should 'app:layout_behavior' be set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181299/where-should-applayout-behavior-be-set)

[image]

It is still not working as you can see here is my code:

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="395dp"
            android:layout_height="659dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nothing seems to work (maybe because of the view pager?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this instead of including multiple layout just use one in your acticity_main.xml

```
**enter code here**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, copy and pasted your code and it worked. I guess selecting drawer activity on project start is not correct.

Comment: no there is nothing related with selection this is simple layout rules . even if u try just by changing CoordinatorLayout with linearLayout in app_bar_main.xml it will work, i just simplified it in one xml.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. Im going to read up on layout rules.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in xml but you can convert to Constraintlayout based on requirement. It's simple UI I have deign to help you and understand

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tasks.TasksActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/viewpager  />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_add_task"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/contentFrame"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                app:fabSize="normal" />
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_actions" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: So what should I change to fix my problem?

Comment: @Dave in app_bar_main.xml using coordinate is bit wrong it inflate one view on another so there must be LinearLayout instead of CoordinateLayout and you can used coordinate top of view pager for adding fab or bottom sheet. That simple