# the appbar is coming above the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I create a navigation drawer activity, then I create a blank fragment and inside it I dropped a recyclerView, in app_bar_main.xml file the recyclerview is coming under the appbar

Here is the app_bar_main.xml code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Test1.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Test1.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

[here it how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIHVN.png)

its my first time using stack overflow sry for the bad format

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33422715/11805824) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in your `content_main.xml` file put this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` in your root layout

Comment: still same issue, in my content_main i have a fragment , inside the fragment i have the recyclerView